# FTPClient gets connection time out after 2 succesfull file uploads

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I am using FTPClient and sending file to FTP server every 30 second by Timer, interestingly I get connection timeout error after 2 succesfull uploads, a third one would not happen  and the error as follows, tested many times with different settings and same result;

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:285)
at com.xxxxx.PDF2VS.send2FTP(PDF2VS.java:87)
at com.xxxxx.PDF2VS$1.run(PDF2VS.java:35)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

and here is code I found to send file;

```
   public static boolean send2FTP ()   
       {
          FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
          FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
            //read from the 
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream in = PDF2VS.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

            prop.load(in);
            client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
            client.connect(prop.getProperty("FTP_ADDRESS"));
            client.login(prop.getProperty("UNAME"), prop.getProperty("PWD"));
            System.out.print("Message : " + client.getReplyString());

            client.setDefaultPort(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("PORT")));
            int f1 = client.getDefaultPort();
            client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            System.out.println("File transfer port no  " + f1);
            System.out.println("FTP server reply ." + client.getReplyString());

            String localfile = prop.getProperty("LOCAL_FILE");
            fis = new FileInputStream(localfile);

            int lastSlash = localfile.lastIndexOf('/');
            String filename = localfile.substring(lastSlash+1);

            System.out.println("Uploading: " + filename);
            System.out.println("file : "+fis);

            client.setFileTransferMode(2);
            System.out.println("Flag reply ." + client.getReplyString());

            boolean flag = client.storeFile(filename,fis);

            System.out.println("Flag reply ." + client.getReplyString());

            if (flag) {
                System.out.println("Successfully uploaded the file");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Not able to upload the file");
            }

            fis.close();
            client.logout();
            System.out.println("Logout ." + client.getReplyString());

            in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            try {
                client.disconnect();
                System.out.println("Server Disconnected." + client.getReplyString());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                 ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

return true; 
}
```

It does work 2 times and receives error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked, that the server doesn't have a limit regarding how many files can be uploaded in rapid succession? Also, how large are the files? It will not happen, that two files are transmitted at the same time, right? (Per protocol, FTP can only transfer one file per control connection)

Comment: I know that the server can handle any files because I am able to test manually with same file and no problem.  Files arr 17kb. No transmission at the same time, 30 seconds delay. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Could it be because you are essentially logging in and logging out each time? What happens if you use the same connection?

Comment: Tried that too, no luck, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you ever solved this?